# How can I block all programs inside a folder to connect to the internet in Windows?

Tags: group-policy, windows-firewall

I want to block all programs inside a folder to connect to the internet.

Is there any way either using Windows Firewall or Group policy to block
all programs inside a folder ?

Comment: Doubtful. There used to be a way to do this using MS ISA Server and the firewall client, but I don't recall ever working on an ISA environment where it was used. ISA is now called Forefront TMG I think, it might be able to do it, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any way to block everything within a specific folder.  You would need to know what applications are installed within that folder and create specific rules for each application.  These could then be pushed down to the end users computers via GPO.